# How to assign the result of a query into a variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I have this query:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tablename WHERE id = 'n';
```

**Note:** `n` is unique and always the result of query above is *one* row.

---

Now I want to store `col1` and `col2` into a variable. Something like this:

```
SET @var_name = SELECT col1, col2 FROM tablename WHERE id = 'n';
```

As you see, there is two columns. So I want to know how can I get the value of those columns separately?

---

In reality I want to use that like this:

```
SET @var_name = SELECT col1, col2 FROM tablename WHERE id = 'n';

IF ( @var_name[col1] = 'x' AND @var_name[col2] = 'xx' ) THEN
    -- do stuff
ELSEIF ( @var_name[col1] = 'y' AND @var_name[col2] = 'yy' ) THEN
    -- do stuff
END IF;
```

But my syntax doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would store it in *two* variables as:

```
SELECT @var1 := col1, @var2 := col2
FROM tablename
WHERE id = 'n';
```

You could get a string representation of the two values using some form of concatenation:

```
SELECT @var := CONCAT_WS(', ', col1, col2)
FROM tablename
WHERE id = 'n';
```

However, MySQL variables are not arrays, so you are limited to numeric and string types.